# (Unity)DirectoryNotFoundException - how to save screenshot on external folder?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, file-io

What I want to is writing screenshot on external folder, but it fail with `DirectoryNotFoundException` Error.

Because security problem, Unity Project can't write image file on its directory folder. So, I tried to save screenshot with external path, but unity editor search path from its project directory, not from root folder.

for example,

Project folder : `C:\unity_Project1\`

Where I want to save screeshot : `C:\unity\Screenshot\`

then

> Error message : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Unity_Projects1\C\Unity\Screenshot\20210203121329.png".

here's my code

```
IEnumerator Rendering ()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    byte[] imgByte;
    string path = @"C:\Unity\Screenshot\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".png";
    path = path.Replace(":", "");
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0, false);
    texture.Apply();

    imgByte = texture.EncodeToPNG();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imgByte);
}
```

What is the problem? and how can i solve it?

Comment: This creates a difference when the editor wants to implement this process or creates your project according to the target platform.  Please take a look...

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/persistence-saving-and-loading-data

Comment: Dont replace “:” on the whole path. As you arent getting what you thought. It will have made it “C\Unity\Screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

What happens is after you remove the `:` from the entire path (for some unknown reason) you convert `C:\...` to `C\...` which converts your supposedly harddrive's root directory into a normal folder called `C`.

This makes `File.WriteAllBytes` automatically interpret and use it as a [**relative** path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm) starting at your current executing directory (your Unity project folder)

```
C:\Unity_Projects1\
```

and adding your malformed path

```
C\Unity\Screenshot\20210203121329.png
```

as a **relative** path which as you can see in your error message results in the path

```
C:\Unity_Projects1\C\Unity\Screenshot\20210203121329.png
```

which obviously is wrong.

---

Your custom `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")` already results in a string without any `:` anyway so simply use

```c#
var folderPath = Path.Combine("C:\\", "Unity", "Screenshot");
var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".png");

// creates the folder and subfolders unless they already exist
Directory.CreateDiectory(folderPath);

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imgByte);
```

---

Then as already suggested by others in general you might still not have the permissions to e.g. create a new folder directly on `C:\`.

You might want to consider rather storing your files in [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) (or while testing in the UnityEditor to [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html))